# Having issues keeping score in javascript Rock, Paper, Scissors Game

Tags: javascript, function

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, but no dice.  I have a function called `gameScore()` that is supposed to keep track of player and computer scores, as well as draws.  I have the scores defined as global variables, so there should be no issue updating them from inside a function.

My issue is that even though I get output in the console saying who wone the game, the scores don't get updated, and the game goes on indefinitely.  Any help is really appreciated, my code is below.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let draws = 0;

//Computer choice
function computerPlay() {
  let random = Math.random();
  if (random <= 0.3333) {
    return "paper";
  } else if (random >= 0.6666) {
    return "rock";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}

//Plays one round of RPS
function playRound(playerChoice, computerSelection) {
  if (playerChoice === computerSelection) {
    return draw;
  } else if (playerChoice === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
    return playerWinRound;

  } else if (playerChoice === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
    return playerWinRound;

  } else if (playerChoice === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
    return playerWinRound;

  } else {
    return computerWinRound;

  }
}

//Specifies round win/game win messages
let playerWinRound = "Player wins this round!"
let computerWinRound = "Computer wins this round!"
let draw = "Draw!"
let playerWin = "Player wins the game! Congratulations!"
let computerWin = "Computer wins the game! Congratulations!"


//For loop that plays multiple rounds
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  let playerChoice = prompt("Rock, paper, or scissors?").toLowerCase();
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  let roundResult = playRound(playerChoice, computerSelection);
  console.log(roundResult);
  gameScore(roundResult);
  console.log("Your score is " + playerScore);
  console.log("The computer's score is " + computerScore);

  if (playerScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
    break;
  }
}


//Keeps score and prints out correct messages based on score
function gameScore() {
  let result = playRound()

  if (result === playerWinRound) {
    playerScore++;
  } else if (result === draw) {
    draws++;
  } else {
    computerScore++;
  }


  if (playerScore === 5) {
    console.log(playerWin);
    return;
  }
  if (computerScore === 5) {
    console.log(computerWin);
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already do have the result of the round and you pass it on to `gameScore`with `gameScore(roundResult);`, however, there you don't actually use that argument, but you create another round:

```
 function gameScore() {
   let result = playRound()
```

instead, just take the result passed:

```
function gameScore(result) {
```